# MIC2251 5V Booster - voltage drops when load is connected

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, load, voltage

I have a step-up circuit that boosts 2.8-4.2V on the input to 5V.
The problem is when I connect any load to it at the output, it loses around 1V and I have no idea why.

The Step-up IC is MIC2251:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC2251-High-Efficiency-Low-EMI-Boost-Regulator-DS20006487A.pdf

Diode 1N5817RLG: https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/1n5817-d.pdf

Inductor B78108E1103K000: https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/30/ds/b78108_148e.pdf

Capacitor (two of these in parallel FG28X5R1E106MRT06): https://product.tdk.com/en/system/files?file=dam/doc/product/capacitor/ceramic/lead-mlcc/catalog/leadmlcc_halogenfree_fg_en.pdf

I'm doing the tests with a lab power supply "simulating" the voltage levels from a single cell Li-ion battery(2.8V-4.2V), this power supply can deliver up to 3A and as I'm using an LED with its respective resistor as load I don't think the problem is the power supply can't deliver enough power.

Edit: I'm testing this on a breadboard

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you try placing one FG28X5R1E106MRT06 as input capacitor?

Comment: There's your problem=>"I'm testing this on a breadboard."

Comment: yes, the capacitor in the input helps on reducing the noise but still 1V drops.

Comment: @JRE could you please explain how breadboard affects on the voltage drop? I supposed it'd only add noise because of parasitic capacitance/inductance the breadboard has

Comment: Switchers don't work well on breadboards.  The inductance of the pin rows is about on level with the inductor in the circuit.  There's capacitance between the pins that messes with things.  Poor contact through the pin rows causes high resitance to the large currents needed for a switching power supply to work.

Comment: @JRE thanks for the input. Yeah, that makes sense. I'll solder the components on a general purpose PCB right now and post the results

Comment: while @JRE is right about a breadboard setup being a bad one, I have actually never experienced a 1V drop in the output. A few 100mV, yes, but not a whole volt. Can you post a picture of the layout? A compact layout and small jumper wires is what you should use while making DC-DC converters on a breadboard. I have only built 100kHz converters on a breadboard, so I'm not sure how bad the parasitics have an effect on a higher frequency circuit (judging by your L&C values, is it around 300kHz or higher?) Can you post a pic of your layout?

Comment: Soldering the components into a general purpose PCB did solve the problem. Using switchers on breadboards and jumpers as wires proved to be a terrible idea. Thanks everyone for your time and comments

Answer (score 4):

Further to my comment

> while @JRE is right about a breadboard setup being a bad one, I have actually never experienced a 1V drop in the output. A few 100mV, yes, but not a whole volt. Can you post a picture of the layout? A compact layout and small jumper wires is what you should use while making DC-DC converters on a breadboard. I have only built 100kHz converters on a breadboard, so I'm not sure how bad the parasitics have an effect on a higher frequency circuit (judging by your L&C values, is it around 300kHz or higher?) Can you post a pic of your layout?

Here are some pics of a DC-DC converter that I built:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice how I've used tiny wires to make connections instead of using the long, horrible, inductor'y jumper cables. That drastically helps improve the converter's performance.

And here's a thing that I do when I build DC-DC converters: I make use of the split in the bus to have two different voltages in the same "row of dots", if you know what I mean. I only connect one "row of dots" of the left and right side together for a common ground connection between the input and output but I leave the other "row of dots" to the left and right of the break in the bus bar so that I can connect the input voltage on one side and the output voltage on the other.

Also, the way you measure your output voltage also matters. Place your multimeter probe ground on the ground of your DC-DC controller IC and the red probe on the lead of the upper voltage divider resistor and see if you still measure a 1V drop. If you measure directly across your load, then yes, you will see a huge drop in the output voltage. Try it my way and see what kind of results you get.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It is essential that there is a suitable input capacitor.

When the internal switch is enabled it conducts until about 1.6A is flowing through the inductor and the switch. It then turns off and the inductor discharges into the load. This current has to come mainly from the input capacitor or the voltage will briefly drop. It must have a very low ESR and there must be low inductance in the loop. (ie short wiring)

In the datasheet, they recommend a 10uF or 22uF ceramic capacitor. Ceramic capacitors have very low ESR. A conventional electrolytic may not be good enough. I have found that tantalum or polymer electrolytic is necessary if not using a ceramic.

Also, be aware of how much current will be needed at the input. With a 2.8V input supply, the current will be at least double that taken from the output. Voltage drop in wiring can easily drop a few hundred millivolts and make things worse.